# TestNg report is getting generated for only last <test> tag on xml

Tags: testng, reporting

I have my tentng.xml in below format :

```
<suite name="Regression Suite" verbose="10" preserve-order="true" configfailurepolicy="continue" thread-count="3" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Name A" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassA">
               
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

        <test name="Name B" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="ClassB">
                </class>
            </classes>
        </test>
     .
     .
    </suite>
```

the tentNg index.html report generated for it contains the results only for the class under the last test tag. Has anyone ever faced this issue and knows a solution to it?

Comment: looks their is open issue in testng https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1423

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the parallel argument from your .xml do you still have the issue?  I had a similar issue when running in parallel in gradle. If that works, try setting it to run parallel `classes` instead of `tests`. This is what I had to do ultimately to get all tests to report when running in gradle.